# Separar por renglón la información recibida por formulario de contacto vía php

Tags: php, email

Estoy utilizando un código en **PHP** para enviar un correo desde un formulario de mi sitio en una de mis páginas. El mail lo recibo sin problemas y lo puedo ver cómo llega a la cuenta de mi correo. Pero me gustaría poder separar la información que viene desde el formulario que el usuario me envía. Por ejemplo, que al leerlo desde mi mail me quede de la siguiente forma:

Nombre: Juan Perez
Email: jperez@servidordecorreo.com
Asunto: Información sobre los gastos mensuales
Mensaje: Me gustaría por favor que me puedas enviar el resumen de lo trabajado durante los meses de este año. Estoy a la espera, muchas gracias.

Pero ahora me está quedando de la siguiente forma:

Nombre: Juan Perez Email: jperez@servidordecorreo.com Asunto: Información sobre los gastos mensuales Mensaje: Me gustaría por favor que me puedas enviar el resumen de lo trabajado durante los meses de este año. Estoy a la espera, muchas gracias.

O sea, todo junto y pegado. Igual se entiende. Pero sería para mi mejor tenerlo renglón por renglón. Lo raro de todo es que desde php hago uso del `'/r/n'` para bajar una línea al final de cada información y no pasa nada, también probé sólo con `'/n'` y sin resultado.

También aclarar que tuve que agregar el parámetro opcional `'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'` en `mail()` porque si no me pone,  por ejemplo, caracteres raros en los acentos. Si saco ese parámetro opcional si funciona y me separa la información por renglón. Pero no lo quiero sacar ya que los mensajes sino vienen con caracteres raros, como ya comenté.
Acá les dejo la parte del código en **PHP** de cómo está realizado:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])){
    if($_POST['Email'] and $_POST['Mensaje']){
    $cuerpo = "Nombre: " . $_POST["Nombre"] . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["Email"] . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Asunto: " . $_POST["Asunto"] . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST["Mensaje"] . "\r\n";
    ini_set ("SMTP", "glosarioit.com");
    mail('info@miservidor.com','Formulario recibido',$cuerpo,'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');?>
    <script> alert("Mensaje enviado correctamente. Responderemos a la brevedad, muchas gracias.")</script>
<?php }else{?>
    <script> alert("Los campos E-mail y Mensaje son requeridos.")</script>
<?php }}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar la etiqueta `<br>` (salto de línea) en vez de `\r\n` para separar el `$cuerpo` de tu correo ya que se enviará como html

Comment: Si anduvo. No me había dado cuenta de eso y no pense que podía ser tan simple.  
Ahora me quedo de esta forma `$cuerpo = "Nombre: " . $_POST["Nombre"] . "<br>";` lo mismo hice en las demás líneas.
Muchas gracias @varTob